# Issue with Graphql in React fetching with a nested object - Object is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, graphql

> Update when I plug in the userID with an argument, it works, but not
> with the parameter in the graphql fetch
>
> The backend works with graphql in the playground, on the frontend
> with the Apollo Dev Tool shows it reaches the client. Console log
> gives "GetUserId is undefined'
>
> [Dashboard - Frontend]

```
        import React from "react";
        import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
        import PostCard from "../../components/PostCard";
        import gql from graphql-tag;
```

> ```
>        attempting to fetch data on the frontend
> ```

```
          export default function Dashboard() {
          const { loading, data } = useQuery(FETCH_POST_QUERY);
          if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
          const { getUserPost: userId } = data;
    
  return (
    <div className="PostCard">
      <h1>Host Events</h1>
      {userId.CreatedEvents.map((list) => (
        <PostCard
          //add img
          id={list.id}
          key={list.id}
          title={list.title}
          description={list.description}
          price={list.price}
          address={list.address}
          date={list.date}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

> fetch from graphql - not sure if this formatted correctly

```
const FETCH_POST_QUERY = gql`
  query getUserPost($userId: ID!) {
    getUserPost(userId: $userId) {
      createdEvents {
        id
        address
        category
        date
        description
        price
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

> [User Schema] -
> Having issue with the nested createdEvents

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  email: String,
  createdAt: String,
  createdEvents: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Post",
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = model("User", userSchema);
```

> ```
> [Resolver]
> ```
>
> - working on the backend

```
    async getUserPost(_, { userId }) {
      // Query into creator nested scheme
      const events = async (eventIds) => {
        try {
          const events = await Post.find({ _id: { $in: eventIds } });
          return events.map((event) => {
            return {
              ...event._doc,
              id: event.id,
              creator: user.bind(this, event.creator),
            };
          });
        } catch (err) {
          throw err;
        }
      };

      const user = async (userId) => {
        try {
          const user = await User.findById(userId);
          return {
            ...user._doc,
            id: user.id,
            createdEvents: events.bind(this, user._doc.createdEvents),
          };
        } catch (err) {
          throw err;
        }
      };
      // Nested createdEvents
      const event = await User.findById(userId);
      return {
        ...event._doc,
        id: event.id,
        createdEvents: events.bind(this, event._doc.createdEvents),
      };
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> Got it to work!

import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import PostCard from "../../components/PostCard";
import { AuthContext } from "../../context/auth";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export default function Dashboard() {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { loading, data } = 
  useQuery(FETCH_POST_QUERY, {
    variables: { userId: context.user.id },
  });

  console.log(context.user);

  if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  const { getUserPost: userId } = data;

  return (
    <div className="PostCard">
      <h1>Host Events</h1>
      {userId.createdEvents.map((list) => (
        <PostCard
          // Add img
          id={list.id}
          key={list.id}
          title={list.title}
          description={list.description}
          price={list.price}
          address={list.address}
          date={list.date}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

// Query into a nested object -> User -> 
     CreatedEvents -> post
    const FETCH_POST_QUERY = gql`
    query getUserPost($userId: ID!) {
    getUserPost(userId: $userId) {
      createdEvents {
        id
        address
        category
        date
        description
        price
        title
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score -1):

You are telling in your FETCH_POST_QUERY to pass userId as input parameter and it cannot be null but forgot to pass userId from frontend. The query will look something like this:

```
      const { loading, data } = useQuery(FETCH_POST_QUERY,{variables:{userId:1}});
```

Comment: const { getUserPost: userId } = data;

Comment: How can you destructure data when theres no data? userId is required as input param to get the data

Comment: Thanks you for the help from Nepal, would give you a star, but I am newbie status.